# Google forms checkbox results as new rows in google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to implement the accepted solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354837/google-sheets-checkbox-results-as-new-rows) and have my form with checkboxes be automatically converted to a proper pivotable list, just like the OP.

I cannot get the code snippet for `advancedSplit` to run automatically when the form is submitted.

I can get `advancedSplit` to split a row of responses into multiple rows, but only if I enter the formula manually.

I have tried various combinations of ArrayFormula making use of `advancedSplit` in the 1st row of the Form Responses sheet to get the split to execute automatically no avail.

any ideas?

Comment: Could you reformat your post to ask a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have this working, I skipped the `advancedSplit` code and rolled my own in javascript, and tied it to `onFormSubmit` trigger to have it run whenever the form is submitted.  repaired data are written to a separate sheet in the same workbook.

I dragged the columns the form writes into the order such that it's the first column that is the comma separated names list from the checkboxes.  all the other columns are duplicated for each name in the list.

working code as follows:

```
    function repairFormEntries() {
  // function breaks csv field returned by form submission checkbox field into multiple rows

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('xxxxxxx');
  var raw_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Raw responses');
  var repaired_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Repaired responses');

  var last_rawrow = raw_sheet.getLastRow();  // row number with newly added raw data
  var rawRow = (raw_sheet.getRange(last_rawrow,1,1,6).getValues())[0]; //0th element because only one row of data

  var names = rawRow[0].split(", ");  // split checkbox names into new array called names
  for (var i=0; i < names.length; i++) {
    var name = names[i];
    var repairedRow = [name];  // create new array of data for entry to repaired sheet
    repairedRow = repairedRow.concat(rawRow.slice(1));  // append remainder of original data from 2nd column (element 1)
    repaired_sheet.appendRow(repairedRow); // add to the bottom of the list
  }

}
```